# Can't seem to grab array from object on return of mongoose document success

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm saving a document into a mongodb collection and upon success im returning the document.

ie:

```
ProductHistory.findOneAndUpdate(
        {productId: product._id},
        $push: {'history': historyData },
        {upsert: true, new: true})
.exec((err, success) => {
    if (err){
         console.log('Error: ', err)        
    }
    console.log('success is: ', success)
}
```

The result is successfully saved entry and a console logged object which looks like the following:

```
{
    _id: 616eb07b1e7edf6e9b035707,
    history: [
            {
                    _id: 61b7cdb160854a0564c15f25,
                    value: 114.5,
            },
            //...repeated objects x times
    ]
}
```

The problem is I want to access history so I can perform a `forEach` on it but I'm having trouble selecting it.

If i do
`console.log('success is:' , success.history)` it returns undefined.

Likewise if i do `success.history.map()`. I've also tried destructing is using:

```
const {history} = success
```

I just can't seem to grab that array for some reason! any ideas please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without viewing your Mongoose schema, I can't say for certain. However, more than likely you haven't added the `history` array type to your schema.

### Solutions

1. Add this array to your schema (preferred method).
2. You should be able to bypass the schema by accessing `success._doc` object. This is *not* recommended and should only be used for testing and whatnot during development.